# Understanding PHP Arrays from a Python background

Tags: php, python

I typically code in Python, Java, or C. I'm taking on a project in PHP and I'm reading up on arrays in PHP and I'm utterly baffled. If I am understanding correctly, the numerical indices in PHP don't necessarily correspond to position and are just keys like in a dict in Python. So, when you shuffle a PHP array, the order of the elements will change, but their keys will remain the same. So when calling `array[9]`, you might actually be getting the first element of the array if the shuffle ordered the elements that way. This raises a bunch of questions:

- Is a PHP array, then, always just some kind of ordered hash table?
  And what does that mean for overhead? In Python, lists function like
  a classic array data structure and dictionaries more along the lines
  of a hash structure. PHP seems to combine the two by assigning unique
  keys to every value AND keeping track of the order of those values. If I want to use an associative array structure for constant time lookup, am I in a far worse off position than I would be with a Python dictionary because of this ordering overhead? Are there PHP data structures that are ONLY arrays or ONLY hash tables?
- What happens when you remove a value from a numbered PHP array? If I 
  have an array, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, I remove 4 from the array, and then
  try to access `array[3]`, is it going to give me an error, since I
  removed the element with the key 3? Or does PHP do some kind of key
  adjusting in such a case?
- If you change the ordering of an array (i.e., through a sort or a
  shuffle), is the only way to have the indices correspond to the
  position to copy the array to a new array using `array_values()`.

Comment: In response to your last point: make sure to read through [this list of PHP pitfalls](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#arrays), as well as the entire rest of that article, before you write any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php
2. This code:

   ```
   $arr = array(0,1,2,3,4);
   unset($arr[3]);
   echo $arr[3];  // undefined index warning, execution continues;
   echo isset($arr[3]) ? $arr[3] : '';
   print_r($arr);
   ```

   The `print_r()` outputs:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => 0
       [1] => 1
       [2] => 2
       [4] => 4
    )
   ```
3. This [depends on the function you choose](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php). Some maintain index association, some do not.

### Protip:

- Never expect two seemingly-similar PHP functions to behave anything like each other. It's the "English" of programming languages: full of crap stolen from other languages and loads of conventions that contradict each other, but everyone speaks it so hop on board the freedom train.

  'murca.